# Android orientation trick needed

Tags: java, android, orientation

So i have a web view in a activity

I need it to **keep orientation the same as the one the devices was in, when user opened activity** (so if LANDSCAPE when activity was opened -> keep that!..if PORTRAIT -> keep that)

So

- dont need XML manifest notation.. i dont want to force a specific orientation, just to keep opened one!

These two tentatives do nothing:

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(null);
```

or

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      newConfig.orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

So ideas??

Answer (score 0):

For Fix activity Oriention

set Mani-feast activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: again dont want to force a specific orientation..just keep the one with which the activity was instantiated!

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on Androids activity lifecycle.
when you re-open an activity a new instance is built. Therefore there was no "previous" orientation. 
if you want the same orientation you had when you paused the activity you should store the previous orientation in a value that persists through the lifecycle.

edit: if you want your examples to work you should declare them in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

putting android:configChanges="orientation" in your manifest under your activities tells android that the activity will handle screen orientation changes itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to implement that feature but this should work:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) // you only want to save orientation when you are loading the activity for the first time
    {
        ((MyApp)getApplication()).orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; // I saved the orientation in the application class, but you can save it anywhere you like except in "this"
        Log.d("test", "orientation in onCreate: "+((MyApp)getApplication()).orientation);
    }

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("test", "setContentview with orientation in onResume "+((MyApp)getApplication()).orientation);
    if(((MyApp)getApplication()).orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_portrait);
    }
    else if(((MyApp)getApplication()).orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_landscape);
    }
}
```

On a side note, it's a bad idea to me to force the orientation like that.

Comment: webview (js + html) will have weird look if i dont!

Comment: oh i just got another "great" idea. Why don't you check the orientation before this activity is started?
Something like 
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)